# Early return from a Scala constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, exit

I am writing the constructor for my "main" class. The first thing it does is call a method to use commons-cli to parse the command line. If the `parseOptions` method returns false, an error has occurred, and the constructor should exit.

I tried writing the following code

```
if (!parseOptions(args)) return
```

but the compiler complains that I have a "Return statement outside method definition".

Short of calling `System.exit(1)` or inverting the boolean (and putting all of the rest of my logic inside the `if` statement, is there any way to return "early" from a constructor?

I suppose I could have the `parseOptions` method throw an `IllegalArgumentException` and catch that in my `Main` object.

Thanks.

Comment: While I agree with the other answers that no constructor should return normally if it was unable to put the instance in a state that satisfies its class's invariants, I wonder why you're averse to using `if`?

Comment: If I have several conditions that can all result in an early return, I will end up with an `if` cascade many levels deep.

Comment: So? If that's the logic of your constructor, that's the logic of your constructor. It's also generally advised *not* to have a lot of complex logic in your constructors. Ideally they just "jot down" the values that comprise the instance's state / value.

Comment: @Randall: I do agree with the last point (non-complex constructors).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is there any way to return "early" from a constructor

No. But in your case it sounds like bad design, anyway.

> If the parseOptions method returns false, an error has occurred

In this case the constructor should throw an exception, not return normally.

Comment: After rethinking (and implementing it using `IllegalArgumentException`), I agree that a bad command line parse deserves an exception.

Answer (score 12):

Dont try to do a early/premature return, this makes your code harder more complex, since the side effects of the return can be hard to understand. Instead use a exception to signal that something is wrong.

You can use require in the constructor. This doesn't return. But it seems like throwing an exception actually fits his situation better.

As in:

```
class MyTest(
private var myValue: Int ){

    require(myValue > 0) // Connected to constructor

}

defined class MyTest

scala> val x = new  MyTest(10)
x: MyTest = MyTest@49ff4282

scala> val y = new MyTest(-10)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:133)
```

Comment: This doesn't _return_. But it seems like throwing an exception actually fits his situation better.

Answer (score 4):

A constructor should always either complete fully, or abort (throw an exception). Anything else leaves your object "half constructed" and thus impossible to reason about.

If in your case, the object is valid even if parseOptions failed, then you can change the condition and continue:

```
if (parseOptions(args)) {
  // rest of constructor
}
```

Comment: the fact that Scala doesn't support return from constructor doesn't mean it's 'impossible to reason about'.

Replace `if (X) return;...` with `if (!x) {...}` and you'll be able to reason as much as you wish.

Comment: Huh? didn't you see that reversing the 'if' is exactly what I suggested? What I said that a constructor should finish or roll-back by throwing an exception. It can't return leaving things undone.